# SPLongOperation window on the end redirects in itself

Tags: 2010, development, modal-dialog, splongoperation

I have a small issue with SPLongOperation, basically what i'm doing i have something to happen in "OnPreLoad" method ...

In this method i start a long processing operation and i call SPLongOperation, after it is done, it should redirect to another page, but instead it redirects to another page, but not the page but the Modal Dialog Window which was showing the message about long operation.

```
using (SPLongOperation operation = new SPLongOperation(this.Page))                             
{
operation.Begin();
 .....
operation.End(web.Url);
}
```

At the end i get, a a page opened in the modal dialog window on top of the old page...

Any suggestions?